# Getting started with nRF24lE1 on RPi2

Tags: pi-2, nrf24l01

I decided to ask you for help because of despair - I don't understend how to start working with my nrf24le1 (**32 pin** version) on Raspberry Pi 2.
What I do:
I connect nrf24le1 using following pins:

```
FCSN (p1.1)-> SPI0 CS0
FMISO (p1.0)-> SPI0 MISO
FMOSI (p0.7)-> SPI0 MOSI
FSCK (p0.5)-> SPI0 SCLK
VDD->3.3V
GND-> GND
RESET-> GND
PROG-> any GPIO port, for example, GPIO5.
```

Then I use library nrf24le1-libbcm2835 downloaded from [here](http://homes-smart.ru/upload/NRF24LE1/nrf24le1-libbcm2835_hs.zip) (it is modified library, original is on [Github](https://github.com/derekstavis/nrf24le1-libbcm2835), but I can't compile it).
I run it by `./nrf24le1 test` and program hangs on `"[nrf24le1] nrf24le1_init: Initializing nRF24LE1"` 
I think that my fault is in connecting PROG and RESET to wrong pins.
Please, can you help me?

[image: Scheme of nrf24le1]
[image: Pinout of nrf24le1]

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already solved this problem: bcm2835 needs root privileges,
  `sudo ./nrf24le1 test` will be correct. Or `sudo chmod u+s nrf24le1`

Comment: Do you mind using only English on the RaspberryPi.SE?

Comment: Hello. Using 'sudo ./nrf24le1 test' I get the result as without sudo, and after I executed 'sudo chmod u+s nrf24le1' it returns me 'bcm2835_init: Unable to open /dev/mem: Permission denied
bcm2835 init failed'

Comment: I recommend that you download the new version of the programming and execute it install sudo make install. I also faced this problem and found that it can be easily solved.